# Adding a two strings and displaying in a list box

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I have a webform which once completed stores the data in a string and I need it to add what was stored to another string which displays the text in a list box (on a seperate page than the webform).

I'm pretty clueless on how to make this happen (I know it needs to be called and added but I'm not sure how to do so).

Heres is the class for the webform:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string non_fiction;
    string fiction;
    string self_help;

    protected void Submit_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Cat_DropDownList.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            fiction = "Title: " + Titletxt.Text + " | " + "Description: " + Descriptiontxt.Text + " | " + "Price: " + Pricetxt.Text + " | " + "Quantity: " + Quantitytxt.Text;
        }

        if (Cat_DropDownList.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            non_fiction = "Title: " + Titletxt.Text + " | " + "Description: " + Descriptiontxt.Text + " | " + "Price: " + Pricetxt.Text + " | " + "Quantity: " + Quantitytxt.Text;

        }

        if (Cat_DropDownList.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            self_help = "Title: " + Titletxt.Text + " | " + "Description: " + Descriptiontxt.Text + " | " + "Price: " + Pricetxt.Text + " | " + "Quantity: " + Quantitytxt.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the class for the other page which contains the listbox the new book should be added to:

```
public partial class partin : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private List<String> books = new List<String>();

    int SortASC(string x, string y){ return String.Compare(x, y);}
    int SortDESC(string x, string y){ return String.Compare(x, y) * -1;}

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Header_Label.Text = "Welcome! Please select a book category.";
        }
    }

    protected void Fiction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PopulateFiction();
    }

    protected void PopulateFiction()
    {
        Item_Listbox.Items.Clear();
        Header_Label.Text = "Fiction Section";

        books.Add("Title: The Old Man and The Sea | Decription: An epic novel. | Price: 10 USD | Quantity: 3");
        books.Add("Title: A Game of Thrones | Decription: A tale of fire and ice. | Price: 15 USD | Quantity: 6");
        books.Add("Title: Dracula | Decription: A book about vampires. | Price: 5 USD | Quantity: 7");
        books.Add("Title: Twilight | Decription: An awful book. | Price: Free | Quantity: 1000");

        Item_Listbox.DataSource = books;
        Item_Listbox.DataBind();

        ViewState["books"] = books;
    }

    protected void Non_Fiction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Header_Label.Text = "Non-Fiction Section";

        Item_Listbox.Items.Clear();
        Header_Label.Text = "Fiction Section";

        books.Add("Title: zzzThe Old Man and The Sea | Decription: An epic novel. | Price: 10 USD | Quantity: 3");
        books.Add("Title: zzzA Game of Thrones | Decription: A tale of fire and ice. | Price: 15 USD | Quantity: 6");
        books.Add("Title: zzzDracula | Decription: A book about vampires. | Price: 5 USD | Quantity: 7");
        books.Add("Title: zzzTwilight | Decription: An awful book. | Price: Free | Quantity: 1000");

        Item_Listbox.DataSource = books;
        Item_Listbox.DataBind();

        ViewState["books"] = books;
    }

    protected void Self_Help_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Header_Label.Text = "Self Help Section";
    }

    protected void Sort_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        books = (List<string>)ViewState["books"];
        if (e.CommandName == "Sort")
        {
            switch (e.CommandArgument.ToString())
            {
                case "ASC":
                    books.Sort(SortASC);
                    break;
                case "DESC":
                    books.Sort(SortDESC);
                    break;
            }
        }
        Item_Listbox.DataSource = books;
        Item_Listbox.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use ViewState for what you want to accomplish, which (I think) is posting a newly entered book to another page that shows all books in the category.  You can use the PostBackUrl property of the Submit button so that the form does not post "back" to the same page, but instead posts to another page (in your case partin.aspx).  You would write the button properties in html like so:

```
<asp:Button ID="Submit_btn" runat="server" onclick="Submit_btn_Click" PostBackUrl="~/partin.aspx" Text="Submit" />
```

Then, on the page you posted to (partin.aspx), you will want to retrieve the values that were entered.  You can do that by using the Request.Form Property like in this method:

```
private string GetBookAddedToForm()
{
    string bookDetails  = "Title: " + Request.Form["Titletxt"] + " | " + "Description: " + Request.Form["Descriptiontxt"] + " | " + "Price: " + Request.Form["Pricetxt"] + " | " + "Quantity: " + Request.Form["Quantitytxt"];
        return bookDetails;
}
```

Here is the html for the default page.

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#"  AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2._Default" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head><title>StackOverflow Question</title></head>
<body>
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
    <p>
        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Category" />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="Cat_DropDownList" runat="server" Height="21px" 
            Width="161px"></asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Title" /><asp:TextBox ID="Titletxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br/>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Description" /><asp:TextBox ID="Descriptiontxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br/>
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Price" /><asp:TextBox ID="Pricetxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br/>
        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Quantity" /><asp:TextBox ID="Quantitytxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </p>
    <p>
        <asp:Button ID="Submit_btn" runat="server" onclick="Submit_btn_Click" PostBackUrl="~/partin.aspx"
            Text="Submit" />
    </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code behind for Default.aspx page.  You do not need any code in the submit_click event because you handle the selection in the page it was posted to.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] categories = new string[] { "fiction", "non_fiction", "self_help" };
        Cat_DropDownList.DataSource = categories;
        Cat_DropDownList.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Submit_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    } 
}
```

Now the html for partin.aspx.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="partin.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.partin" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="Header_Label" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="Category_DropDownList" runat="server" Height="16px" 
            Width="208px"></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:ListBox ID="Item_Listbox" runat="server" Height="166px" Width="992px"></asp:ListBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And now for the meat of it.  The ShowBooks method determines what type of book was posted on the previous page and then adds it to the listbox on the partin.aspx page.  It grabs whatever books have already been added into the repository, then adds the newly posted book to it by calling the GetBookAddedToForm method.

```
public partial class partin : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                string[] categories = new string[] { "fiction", "non_fiction", "self_help" };
                Category_DropDownList.DataSource = categories;
                Category_DropDownList.DataBind();
                Header_Label.Text = "Welcome! Please select a book category.";
                string categorySelected = Request.Form["Cat_DropDownList"];
                ShowBooks(categorySelected);
            } 
        }

        private void ShowBooks(string category)
        {
            Item_Listbox.Items.Clear();
            List<string> books = null;
            switch(category)
            {
                case "fiction" :
                    Header_Label.Text = "Fiction Section";
                    books = GetFictionBooks();
                    break;
                case "non_fiction":
                    Header_Label.Text = "Non-Fiction Section";
                    books = GetNonFictionBooks();
                    break;
                case "self_help":
                    Header_Label.Text = "Self Help Section";
                    books = GetSelfHelpBooks();
                    break;
            }
            books.Add(GetBookAddedToForm());
            Item_Listbox.DataSource = books;
            Item_Listbox.DataBind(); 
        }

        private string GetBookAddedToForm()
        {
            string bookDetails  = "Title: " + Request.Form["Titletxt"] + " | " + "Description: " + Request.Form["Descriptiontxt"] + " | " + "Price: " + Request.Form["Pricetxt"] + " | " + "Quantity: " + Request.Form["Quantitytxt"];
            return bookDetails;
        }

        protected List<string> GetFictionBooks()
        {
            List<String> books = new List<String>(); 
            books.Add("Title: The Old Man and The Sea | Decription: An epic novel. | Price: 10 USD | Quantity: 3");
            books.Add("Title: A Game of Thrones | Decription: A tale of fire and ice. | Price: 15 USD | Quantity: 6");
            books.Add("Title: Dracula | Decription: A book about vampires. | Price: 5 USD | Quantity: 7");
            books.Add("Title: Twilight | Decription: An awful book. | Price: Free | Quantity: 1000");
            return books;
        } 

        private List<string> GetNonFictionBooks()
        {
            List<string> books = new List<string>();
            books.Add("Title: zzzThe Old Man and The Sea | Decription: An epic novel. | Price: 10 USD | Quantity: 3"); 
            books.Add("Title: zzzA Game of Thrones | Decription: A tale of fire and ice. | Price: 15 USD | Quantity: 6"); 
            books.Add("Title: zzzDracula | Decription: A book about vampires. | Price: 5 USD | Quantity: 7"); 
            books.Add("Title: zzzTwilight | Decription: An awful book. | Price: Free | Quantity: 1000");
            return books;
        }

        private List<string> GetSelfHelpBooks()
        {
            return new List<string>();
        }
```

Hope this helps you solve your problem.